# style not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building an expandable grid portfolio but the styles for the    `.showcase <a>` tag and `<p>` tag are not showing up. I am not sure why. I think it has something to do with `.html()` not grabbing the `<a>` and `<p>` selector but just the content inside it. Though this does not happen to the `<img>` tag. I am a little baffled. Here is my jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/theMugician/L2xyatfd/38/

Hey everyone I figured out what my problem was. I was calling `html()` twice which makes a lot of sense now. In the variables `$aTag` and `$html` I didn't need to call the `html()` because I was going to call it again in the `.showcase` div.

```
var $aTag = $a.eq($item.data('rel'));
var $html = $p.eq($item.data('rel'));

<!---.showcase div--->
$link.html($aTag).show(0);
$details.html($picture).show(0);
```

Here is the new fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/theMugician/L2xyatfd/47/

Comment: So there's your JS Fiddle, now: add your (minimal) relevant "[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)" code into your question, please.

Comment: The fiddle is a good reproduction of your situation. However, it is also encouraged that the code in the fiddle be placed in the body of your question as demonstration. In general, it is advised to make a post that can stand on its own without following any links. Long story short, please include the code from your fiddle in the question body here.

Comment: I don't get it, you realize you're moving the elements outside `#portfolio-details` when you show them, and that any styles set on  `#portfolio-details p` etc. wont apply ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply try :

```
var $aTag = $a.eq($item.data('rel'));
var $html = $p.eq($item.data('rel'));

$link.append($aTag).show(0);
$images.append($picture).show(0);
```

It will wrap the element, not just its html content